# Is it okay to dye hair?

Tags: karate, social

Is it okay to dye your hair while in martial arts? I want to dip dye it a different color. I'm pretty high up and a few of the younger students see me as a role-model, and I don't want to dissapoint any of the instructors there. I'm scared dying my hair will dishonor the art, because none of the other students have dyed hair, or any other students at other dojo's we test with. I want to, but if it will put shame on the art, I won't. There are no specifications in our handbook saying that we can't but... any advice?

Answer (score 6):

Dying your hair reflects upon you and your personality, not the art. It allows you to better express yourself, but it doesn't change who you are.

Any approval or disapproval you get as a result is coming from a personal level. The only thing any instructor should be concerned about is whether the dye is likely to leach onto equipment or other classmate's clothing when things start to get sweaty.

Comment: Thank you, I planned on asking one of our female Senpai's if it's okay. that's what I was worried about as well, the bleeding.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best thing to do is to ask your Master/Senior Instructor. This kind of thing can vary widely from school to school, but in most modern styles there is nothing disrespectful about having funky hair.